# UnauthorizedException in reading emails with Oauth 2 using EWS

Tags: php, email, oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices

I am trying to load email list using oauth 2. Following is my code:

```
    <?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use src\API\Type;
use garethp\ews\MailAPI as API;

$token='EwA......';    //access token

$api = API::withCallbackToken('outlook.office365.com', $token);
$mail = $api->getMailItems();
  foreach ($mail as $email) {
    $email = $api->getItem($email->getItemId());
    $email_id=$email->getItemId(); 
    $subject = $email->getSubject();
        $sender = $email->getSender()->getMailbox()->getEmailAddress();
        $body = (string) $email->getBody();

    echo $body;
}
```

but getting response as follows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught garethp\ews\API\Exception\UnauthorizedException
>   in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bephpforTteam\New\php_ews\php-ews-master\src\API\ExchangeWebServices.php:438
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bephpforTteam\New\php_ews\php-ews-master\src\API\ExchangeWebServices.php(356):
>   garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServices->handleNonSuccessfulResponses(NULL,
>   401) #1
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bephpforTteam\New\php_ews\php-ews-master\src\API\ExchangeWebServices\MiddlewareFactory.php(57):
>   garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServices->processResponse(NULL) #2
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bephpforTteam\New\php_ews\php-ews-master\src\API\ExchangeWebServices.php(497):
>   garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServices->garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServices{closure}(Object(garethp\ews\API\MiddlewareRequest),
>   Object(Closure)) #3
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bephpforTteam\New\php_ews\php-ews-master\src\API\ExchangeWebServices\MiddlewareFactory.php(66):
>   garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServices->garethp\ews\API{closure}(Object(garethp\ews\API\MiddlewareRequest)) #4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bephpforTt in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bephpforTteam\New\php_ews\php-ews-master\src\API\ExchangeWebServices.php
>   on line 438